# Можно ли изменить порядок передачи функций в функцию

Tags: c++

```
int func1(int a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int func2(int a)
{
    return a + 2;
}
int func3(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        std::cout << func1(func2(i), func3(i));
    }
}
```

Когда я отлаживал подобный код то заметил что в функцию `func1` первым аргументом передаётся `func3` а затем `func2` для меня это проблема т.к. я написал относительно большой код не учитывая этой особенности языка, и теперь меня интересует можно-ли как-то изменить порядок передачи в функцию что бы сначала выполнилась `func2` затем `func3` а после `func1`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а кто прячется за духом? его комментарии такие странные обычно. 
@SemenSlepakovVolya - да, это такая особенность языка - порядок вычисления параметров не определен. Хотите свой порядок - вначале вычислите их, сохраните в переменные, а потом вызывайте.

Comment: А почему это проблема - ваши функции имеют побочный эффект? Это вообще не есть хорошо уже само по себе. А так ну пусть `func2` тогда и вызывает `func3`, например. Хотите определённости - сделайте её сами.

Answer (score 0):

В стандарте с++ порядок вычисления аргументов [не определен и компилятор имеет право вычислять в любом порядке](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Делайте просто предварительное вычисление

```
int func1(int a, b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int func2(int a)
{
    return a + 2;
}
int func3(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        auto a1 = func2(i);
        auto a1 = func3(i)
        std::cout << func1(a1, a2);
    }
}
```

Если же функции возвращают что то сложное (например, std::vector по значению с миллионом элементов), возможно нужно будет использовать rvalue ссылки с move семантикой, что бы улучшить производительность.